# Python3: Remove complex numbers from a list of numbers

Tags: python-3.x, lambda, list-comprehension

I have sorted lists before, but now I simply want to remove all the complex numbers from a list of numbers I generate with an equation.  I was thinking of using filter after I design the function.  Something along the lines of:

```
filtered=list(filter(lambda x: (code to remove complex numbers), list_of_#)
```

or any other way will work, its just that the list is large and it makes sense to remove them with code vs. by hand/eye.

Thanks!

Comment: `not isinstance(x, complex)`

Comment: thanks, is this for the lamda function or as a stand alone line?

Comment: `filtered = list(filter(lambda x: not isinstance(x, complex), list_of_numbers))`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using cmath for your complex numbers you should be able to just do it with a list comprehension, no lambda functions.

Something along the lines of:

```
filtered = [i for i in list_of_num if i.imag == 0]
```

Comment: thanks.  will that remove it from the list or replace it with zero (false)

Comment: Remove it from the list. If you want to replace them with 0's you can use `filtered = [i if i.imag == 0 else 0 for i in list_of_num]`

Comment: The comp works, should have thought of that, but I was thinking filter would be better.  you rock!

Comment: @11thZone Cool, no worries, enjoy.

Comment: Turns out I need to normalize the numbers instead of booting them, at first I thought that a complex temperature made no physical sense.  But if I normalize the result, I can keep all the values (temperatures) in the array and THEN plot them.